# Problem based on Huygens principle

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, huygens-principle

I think tubelight is a linear source. So it's wavefront should be a cylinder. Since we should see the light through the cylinder which has a specific radii but has the same length of the tubelight. So we should not see anything outside that length or that cylinder. Then why we can see the surroundings which do not lye at the point of cylinder. Reflection or diffuse reflection may be the reason. Then why the intensity of light is similar everywhere around the room. (note: I have said similar not identical since intensity decreases with distance but if there is diffuse reflection then we should have very less intensity(as the wall absorbs some of the light) outside the so-called cylinder.Why does not the the intensity all around the room similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the thing that you aren't considering which might resolve your doubt if the fact that a tube light isn't infinitely long. Thus assuming that the wavefront of the light from is will be a cylinder of increasing radius is not actually correct. The wavefront will also expand along the axis of the cylinder. It would from a cylinder with two hemispherical caps.

Another thing that you are missing is that diffuse reflection isn't as bad as you think. Specifically when you think that almost half the light of the tube will be reflected of the wall behind the tube.